# Is it possible to convert unquoted JSON to either CSV or appropriate JSON format using pyspark

Tags: python, json, pyspark, databricks

I am using pyspark in which I am extacting the required string from log files which is a JSON string but without the quotes. Below is the example:

```
{PlatformVersion=123,PlatformClient=html,namespace=NAT}
```

I want to convert it to either CSV or JSON as I want to further store it into relation DB using data pipelines. Is there a way to achieve converting such string to CSV or JSON?

Comment: Unquoted JSON isn't JSON. This one has also equal signs, which is also not JSON even if it were quoted. You could start off by [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is doing the job.

Steps:

1. remove curly braces
2. split by `,`
3. split by `=`
4. populate the dict with key & value

```
    result = {}
    log_line = '{PlatformVersion=123,PlatformClient=html,namespace=NAT}'
    log_line = log_line[1:-1]
    parts = log_line.split(',')
    for part in parts:
        k,v = part.split('=')
        result[k] = v
    print(result)

output

    {'PlatformVersion': '123', 'PlatformClient': 'html', 'namespace': 'NAT'}
```